# deleted remote branch in IDE how to restore

Tags: git, gitlab, ide

i have problem. I have another remote branch with name "fixed" but his not my. And i deleted this branch in IDE (by accident). How i can restore it, when it was not my repository. Help me please

Comment: Hopefully the person who pushed the branch in the first place still has it locally. If so, they can push it again to recreate it. (My guess was *you* don't have it locally, but if so, of course push it back up yourself)

Comment: no, this person havent localy branch(

Comment: They had to have it at some point to push it to remote. Did you mean that the original branch author already deleted it locally? Even if so, they probably still can find it back in their `reflog`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

try using the command `git reset --soft HEAD~headNumber`, and get back to the desired head position. The head number of desired position can be seen using the git command `git reflog`